# Select several part of 2-d array by the attribute of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Here is my question.

- **a** is a 2-d numpy array in the shape of 100x100 containing finite numbers
- **b** is a 2-d bool array in the shape of 100x100 containing **True and False**

My target:

> Select specific part of array a when the value of b[i,j] == True

My code here:

```
 select = a[np.array(np.where(b == True)).T]
```

But the result shows like some index are out of boundaries.

Does someone has any idea to achieve that?

Comment: won't `a[b]` just work here?

Comment: What shape do you want the output to be?  `a[b]` is the same as `a.flatten()[b.flatten()]`.  It will return a vector with length equal to the number of true values in b.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are transposing the index array. Also you don't need to convert the result of `np.where()` to numpy array, just pass it as index to first array.

Here is an example:

```
>>> b = np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(10,10))
>>> b
array([[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]])
>>> a = np.random.choice(100, size=(10,10))
>>> 
>>> a
array([[47, 90, 94, 11, 17, 65, 95, 57, 36, 43],
       [65, 82, 37, 93, 65, 32,  8, 47, 16, 12],
       [66, 60, 40, 90, 34, 30, 40,  2, 36, 65],
       [ 8, 53, 69,  0, 61, 60, 94, 37, 77, 43],
       [59, 47, 21, 93, 58,  0, 92, 26, 17, 44],
       [98, 16, 33, 56, 39, 30, 14, 93, 93, 58],
       [96, 40, 35, 17, 21, 70, 26,  0, 21, 81],
       [47,  4, 20, 82, 19, 89, 50, 26, 38,  4],
       [60,  3, 72, 56, 78, 55, 60, 53,  3, 87],
       [80,  1, 65,  2, 92, 92, 97, 17, 55, 67]])

>>> a[np.where(b)]
array([11, 65, 95, 82, 37, 47, 16, 12, 66, 60, 40, 90, 34, 36,  8, 53,  0,
       94, 43, 47, 58,  0, 92, 26, 17, 44, 98, 16, 33, 56, 39, 30, 93, 40,
       35, 17,  4, 19, 89, 50,  4, 60, 72, 55, 53, 80,  2, 92, 97, 67])
```

Note that you are not have to use `b==True` as `np.where` condition, when you pass the boolean array it will choose the valid items which are determined by python's [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing).